# Cast std function object back to functor struct

Tags: c++

In this scenario:

```
struct Holder {
    std::function<void()> f;
};
struct Functor { void operator()(){ /**/ } };
int main() {
    Holder = { Functor{} };
    //...
```

Is there a way to later cast `f` back to a `Functor` type?

Comment: The short answer is: no. This what "type erasure" is all about.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: The slightly longer answer is "yes" :-S

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `target` member function is `std::function`'s type-unerasing cast. You'll need to know the target type:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>

struct Functor { void operator()(){ /**/ } };

int main()
{
    std::function<void()> f = Functor();
    Functor * p = f.target<Functor>();
    assert(p != nullptr);
}
```

Comment: That assert is a good idea, you should probably highlight that a bit. AFAIK one doesn't gain ownership of the (pointed to) target instance, do you know whether it's guaranteed to remain valid for the lifetime of the std function instance?

Comment: @DanielJour: If you reassign or swap the function object, you'll surely lose the held target.